# WP plugin commit issue:- svn: E175013: Access to ‘/!svn/me’ forbidden

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins, commit

I did svn checkout plugin code from https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin, made changes in a file and then when I give `svn ci -m ‘changes description’` it asks for user name and password. When I give the username and password, I get the following error message:

```
svn: E175013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175013: Access to ‘/!svn/me’ forbidden
```

I have checked the URL, username and password and all are correct.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: The username that i use for committing is a contributor to the plugin and has all the access.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was not added as a committer.

I was added as a contributor, but not committer. Only committer has access to commit code to their SVN.

To add as committer go to the plugins 'Advanced View' which is there at the right hand sidebar of the plugin owner.

Comment: how much time it takes to new committer can post a update to the repository?

Comment: @Frank it should not take more than a day or two.

Comment: Actually, my username was case sensitive. That's the reason I was unable to commit. @Mika help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have TortoiseSVN installed by any chance? Are you able to view the repository via Repo Browse?

Try using http:// instead of https://

If it's not the username or password, it's usually the URL that's the issue. I'm tempted to say it's the http: protocol instead of https: just based on general observation of what I'm seeing in Google Chrome when trying to view that URL from https: (says that URL doesn't exist on their server).

Comment: I was able to view the repository using the TortoiseSVN Repo browser. 
The URL i mentioned was a dummy URL.